# I have this annoying update that keeps failing and broke my video card driver. What to do?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card

There were problems installing some updates, but we'll try again later. If you keep seeing this and want to search the web or contact support for information, this may help:

Feature update to Windows 10, version 1607 - Error 0x80070005

NVIDIA - Display - 12/29/2016 12:00:00 AM - 21.21.13.7653 - Error 0x80070003

Some update files are missing or have problems. We'll try to download the update again later.

Error code: (0x80070003)

Somewhere along the line I can no longer play any video games like overwatch.

The vga driver is not installed. If I go to device manager and try to find the best driver it gives back microsoft driver. But that's not good enough.

My card is Nvidia gtx 1060

How the hell this kind of problem can happen in the first place anyway? Some update files are missing? How?

Answer (score 1):

You didnt list which Nvidia card you had, but the best thing to do is get the driver from NVidia's [driver page](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).  If you dont know which card you have, it can autodetect it, as well.  This will be the latest driver and NVidia Control Panel.  It will also keep you alerted for updates automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone to the NVIDIA website?  There could also be an issue with the driver.  If you go to the properties of your selected device, you should read all the field entries they have.

Your configuration settings will show you an option that details the setup of the device/driver combination in a setup filed with extension ".INF"